# PHP password_verify incorrectly returning false

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I've searched high and low for this topic, and no one has the same issue I'm experiencing that I could find.

I'm creating a user in a MySQL table, with a hash from password_hash with a strength of 10.

I've been having hell getting it to validate, and have a test script made to actually validate my findings. Here is the script:

```
public function testAction(){
    $data = new dataHandler;
    $data->table = "access";

    $hash1 = $data->insert(array('email'=>'test6@test.com', 'password'=>'ABC123.abc', 'password_confirm'=>'ABC123.abc', 'alias'=>'ABC123.abc'));

    $res = $data->find(array('email'=>'test6@test.com'));

    $hash2 = $res[0]['hash'];

    $test = password_verify('ABC123.abc', $hash1);
    $test2 = password_verify('ABC123.abc', $hash2);

    var_dump($test);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($test2);

    echo "<br><br>";

    echo "Length: " . strlen($hash1) . "<br>{$hash1}<br>Length: " . strlen($hash2) . "<br>{$hash2}";

    die();
}
```

To verify that my script wasn't somehow doing something weird when storing, I made my hash method (called from within the `insert()` method dynamically) echo out the hash directly:

```
public function createHash($password){
    $hash = password_hash($password, HASH);
    echo "Length: " . strlen($hash) . "<br>$hash<br>";
    return $hash;
}
```

Here's the `insert` method. `cleanData` simply `unset`s anything not available in a `describe` - it is not changing any values whatsoever. Warning, it's terribly ugly presently due to a lot of debugging and such:

```
public function insert($data){
    if(!is_array($data)){
        return false;
    } else {
        $this->openDb();
        $ins = "";
        $fs = "";

        $data = $this->cleanData($data);

        foreach($data as $key => $field){
            if($key == "password"){
                $auth = new authorization;

                $key = "hash";
                $field = $auth->createHash($field);

                $data['hash'] = $field;



                unset($data["password"]);
            }

            $ins .= ":{$key}, ";
            $fs .= "`{$key}`, ";
            //$data[$key] = $this->DBH->quote($field);
        }

        $ins = rtrim($ins, ", ");
        $fs = rtrim($fs, ", ");

        try {

            # the shortcut!
            $this->DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $this->DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $STH = $this->DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `" . $this->table . "` ($fs) value ($ins)");

            $STH->execute($data);

            $id = $this->DBH->lastInsertId();

            $this->closeDb();

            return $data['hash']; //Debugging
            return $id;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->errHandler($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here's the output:

```
Length: 60
$2y$10$wGJxGjK4Lz4FgZ3OZJjBo.9lF7LE90p3Q5inOsBROQTU5FBVdj1LK
bool(true) 
bool(false) 

Length: 60
$2y$10$wGJxGjK4Lz4FgZ3OZJjBo.9lF7LE90p3Q5inOsBROQTU5FBVdj1LK
Length: 60
$2y$10$wGJxGjK4Lz4FgZ3OZJjBo.9lF7LE90p3Q5inOsBROQTU5FBVdj1LK
```

As you can see, both `password_verify` attempts fail. The first comes from the hash generation without any further manipulation, the second comes from the database.

What am I doing wrong?

The only thing I could find when searching was people testing and using double quotes, or random human error. This, however, doesn't appear to me to be either of those two.

Comment: What's dataHandler::insert do? If you could atleast post the bit where it actually creates the hash

Comment: I'll put it in the question. Warning, it's ugly as hell due to a lot of debugging and changing of the structure to test.

Comment: There's something weird in the DB. The hash column is a `varchar(255)` and returns a 60 length string. If I set it to a `char(60)` it functions just fine. The output is exactly the same to human eyes: the same string with the same length. Yet, changing the column resolves the problem.

Comment: Does your table contain a `password_confirm` column and an `alias` column? Make sure your `$data` unsets any such keys if they don't exist in the table. Also, what happens if you modify your test to: http://pastie.org/pastes/10506814/text

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question any columns that do not exist are being stripped from the `insert` method. If they did not, I'd be receiving a PDO error and not receiving a hash from the select query.

Comment: Also as previously mentioned, the hash appears _exactly_ the same, therefor it is not logical to assume it is setting the hash field as another value. When returned from the DB, the string is the exact same string as the hash being returned prior to hitting the DB. They are identical in every way, including their length.

Comment: Are you still working with a hash generated from the empty string? Namely `$2y$10$4Y7kQNP/6XyBtQQ4zPI6ZuaelCjHdWE.kBRTUVk56J7PV4BQYWoUS`? If not, please update your question with a new test, and a different hash, preferably using the logic for testing as shown in my link since it clarifies for us that the find only found one record.

Comment: No, I'm getting legitimate hashes in the test. I'll update. I've really just given up hope at this point.

Answer (score 0):

That password hash is for the empty string, try it yourself:

```
<?php
echo password_verify('', '$2y$10$4Y7kQNP/6XyBtQQ4zPI6ZuaelCjHdWE.kBRTUVk56J7PV4BQYWoUS')?'Y':'N';
?>
```

Make sure you're passing createHash a valid `$password`.

Comment: Your example is invalid. You can't use double quotes with that string.

Okay, so the hash listed is the product of an empty string being passed to generate a hash. Interesting...

Comment: Okay, I had a value missing when I changed my `insert` method for testing. The variable itself passes now, and the DB-pulled hash does not. They're still appearing exactly the same, with 60 characters each, but one works and the other does not.

Comment: Does your `$hash1 = $data->insert(...)` statement return the hash? Also, is your `$data->find(...)` statement matching an email which exists more than once in the database? If so, you'd probably want to be selecting the last record with the specified email, not the first. `$hash2 = $res[count($res)-1]['hash'];`.

Comment: In this test example `insert` is returning the hash, yes. Find only matches the first, but `insert` will not allow the same email more than once. It is returning only one record in this example, and shouldn't ever return more than one due to multiple layers preventing duplicate emails. The only exception is if it's a duplicate and one record is soft deleted or marked inactive. `find`, however, will only return active non-deleted records.